# Scala/Spark: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

I am pretty new to scala and spark. Trying to fix my set-up of spark/scala development. I am confused by the versions and missing jars. I searched on stackoverflow, but still stuck in this issue. Maybe something missing or mis-configured.

Running commands:

```
me@Mycomputer:~/spark-2.1.0$ bin/spark-submit --class ETLApp /home/me/src/etl/target/scala-2.10/etl-assembly-0.1.0.jar
```

Output:

```
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "etl"

version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
mainClass := Some("ETLApp")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2" % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2" % "provided";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.5.2";
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-M2";
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.curator" % "curator-recipes" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.curator" % "curator-test" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "args4j" % "args4j" % "2.32"
```

java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"

scala -version
2.10.5

spark version
2.1.0

Any hints welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in that case, your jar must bring all dependend classes along when being submitted to spark.

in maven this would be possible with the assembly plugin and the jar-with-dependencies descriptor. with sbt a quick google found this: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Answer (score 0):

you can change your build.sbt as follows:

```
name := "etl"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-Xfuture",
  "-encoding",
  "UTF-8",
  "-unchecked",
  "-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2" % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2" %  Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.5.2" % Provided,
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-M2",
"org.apache.curator" % "curator-recipes" % "2.6.0",
"org.apache.curator" % "curator-test" % "2.6.0",
"args4j" % "args4j" % "2.32")

mainClass in assembly := Some("your.package.name.ETLApp")

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x: String if x.contains("UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

add the sbt-assembly plugin to your plugins.sbt file under the project directory in your Project's Root directory. Running `sbt assembly` in the Terminal(Linux) or CMD(Windows) in the root directory of your project would download all the dependencies for you and create an U